# My Character not coming to ground after Jump in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am Sorry for the simple question, I have prepared one model in blender and imported it in unity and wants to make ThirdPersonController.

1) I have added the model in the scene and added component -> Rigidbody, Capsule Collider, ThirdPersonCharacter(Script), ThirdPersonUserControl(Script), , which is all by default.

2) I have uploaded the video on this url also - http://tinypic.com/r/34hw8jo/9 for better understanding, here in the last, you see , when i click on space, it jumps but does not come back to ground.

3) I dont know what i am missing ?? , Please help me in this regard

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the flag "use gravity" so your player can experiment that force.

I recomend you to check out the [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) documentation in Unity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: When i use 'use gravity' and make it tick, then my object falls down from the floor (plane) which is having Mesh Collider attach to it (Convex and IsTrigger is not ticked) and When I tick Convex and IsTrigger together and individually, then again my object falls down from the floor.. and When i use Box Collider instead of Mesh Collider then my object will remain in air. never comes on the floor

Comment: Maybe, and is just an idea, you need to check your box collider of the floor.

I can't secure this but it sounds like the box collider is too big and your character is inside them. If you use mesh collider in a plane it will be so thin that your player can't catch the collision and pass throught it.

If you use "isTrigger" it means that it will ignore all physics interactions because a trigger is kind of a flag that knows when an object is in certain area but it doesn't create a collision event  http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html